# Data Modeling Problem - Schema to store approval process

Tags: database-design, schema, design-pattern, physical-design

I need to design a schema to keep track of data changes (I do not need Change Tracking or Change Data Capture or Temporal Tables) to columns in a few tables. When the data is created, modified, or deleted, and when they meet a certain condition, I will have to initiate a workflow to require approval of those changes from groups of users. Are there any known schema design patterns for this purpose?

Comment: Not a lot to go off here and unclear on what you're trying to do. Are you trying to build a revision control system? Can you provide the table structure you currently do have / what the objects are that need to be tracked for changes?